# "<" character ends string in js

Tags: javascript, string, dom

I'm trying to change `<div id="demo"></div>` to `<div id="demo">Hello<World.</div>`

Problem is in my example the result is `<div id="demo">Hello</div>`.

How can I get the result to be `<div>Hello<world.</div>`?

Example:

```js
var str = "Hello<world.";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str; // Hello
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

asd

Comment: Putting **different** code in the question and in JS Fiddle isn't helpful!

Comment: @Quentin don't all 100k+ rep users have the mind-reading ability?

Comment: fixed it. sry didn't expect it to be diferent with console.log

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `innerHTML` that expects a HTML string. Since `<` is used to create tags in HTML, the word `world` is interpretted as a tag name.

Use `textContent` instead:

```js
var str = "Hello<world.";
document.getElementById("demo").textContent = str;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use innerText.

```
var str = "Hello<world.";
document.getElementById("demo").innerText = str;
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use:

```
var str = "Hello&lt;world.";
```

Answer (score 2):

The browser thinks it is the start of a html tag. Try using`&lt;`.

```
var str = "Hello&lt;world.";
console.log(str); // Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

use `textContent` instead of `innerHtml` as `<` is a html string so it treats 'world' as a tag.

```js
var str = "Hello<world.";
document.getElementById("demo").textContent = str;
```

```html
<div id="demo">

</div>
```